# How to read function table (COM type libraries) from unmanaged DLL

Tags: c#, dll, com

I want to get a list of all functions and interfaces that a unmanaged dll provides. My first attempt was to read the export table of the dll, but there are only the 4 standard functions DllRegisterServer, DllUnregisterServer etc. When scanning the dll with dllexp.exe there is a option "Scan COM type libraries". Scaning the dll with that option gives me the wanted informations about interfaces and methods. How can I access this "table" or whatever that is in the pe-file-header to get that functionnames?

If anyone has a working example for c# that would be really awesome.

Comment: Writing your own type library decompiler is not time well-spent, it is readily available.   Like OleView.exe on your machine, File > View Typelib command.  Simplest way is to just add a reference to the file in your project and use Reflection to poke around in the interop library.

Comment: Well, i already have a reference to the native DLL in my Project. The main problem is, that there exists several versions of this dll and not all have the functions implemented that I call from within my application. After re-thinking the situation I came across, that it would be enough to read the major version of the loaded DLL. 
But it would be a nice project to write an own typelib scanner, so if anyone has further information for that, tell me please :)